# Knockout.Validation not showing error messages for property that is loaded after initial rendering

Tags: validation, knockout.js

I have a Knockout.Validation scenario which I think would be fairly common but haven't found a solution from searching around the web and various answers on this site.

The property that I am validating does not get added to the knockout observable until after an ajax call. When validation gets triggered the validation fails and is an error in my validation group but the error message does not get shown on the page. I have made sure all the validation is hooked up by adding validation to a property that does exist when initial render happens and the message shows for that.

I know I could set a default for the property but I wouldn't expect you would have to do that. When i manually add the validation message  with the validationMessage databind property it throws a js error because the property doesn't exist when knockout does its first pass through.....Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "validationMessage: function (){return BlogPost().Title }"
Message: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined.

See this plunk for an example...http://plnkr.co/edit/OhUw8wP2uNypulbcOIbz?p=preview .

```
    self.Errors = ko.validation.group(this, { deep: true });
    self.Count(self.Errors().length);
    if (self.Errors().length === 0) {
        alert("no errors");
    }
    else {
        self.Errors.showAllMessages();
    }
```

It is using require js but that is not causing any issues as for a standard scenario the validation message shows.

What am I missing here to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty clean... move your observables up to the main viewmodel, and leave the updateBlogPost to be just a method (no properties... as it should be).

This allows you to call self.Errors.showAllMessages() after you've loaded the blog post. Not sure you need the update method after this change?

```
function EditBlogPostViewModel(params) {

    var self = this;
    self.BlogPost = ko.observable({});
    self.ErrorsCount = ko.observable(0);

    self.Test = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true });
    self.Count = ko.observable(0);
    self.Errors = ko.validation.group(this, { deep: true });
    self.Count(self.Errors().length);

    blogApiService.getCategories().then(function (categories) {
         return blogApiService.getBlogPost(params.id).then(function (post) {
             self.BlogPost(new BlogPost(post, categories));
             self.Errors.showAllMessages();
        });
    });

}

EditBlogPostViewModel.prototype.updateBlogPost = function () {
    var self = this;
    if (self.Errors().length === 0) {
        alert("no errors");
    }
    else {
        self.Errors.showAllMessages();
    }
};
```

Comment: ... any solution found to your problem?

Comment: no solution found unfortunately. what you have suggested above doesn't fix the problem. the ko.validation.group isnt an observable so when the BlogPost observable is set the validation group doesnt get updated. I may not have explained the issue properly. It is more visible now in the updated plunk as i have set one of the BlogPost observable properties to be an empty string. So when the update is attempted the error message shows for the observable with validation at the top level called Test, that is set early on but not the BlogPost observable property Title.

Comment: @BrettGreen +1 because of illustrating "ko.validation.group(this, { deep: true });" I didn't know about the deep option, and that was keeping my errors from being reported.  Where is that documented?  I can't find it on the Wiki or elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Mark... you can find this documentation here: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration

Answer (score 1):

set deep: true in self.errors property,

```
self.errors = ko.validation.group(self, { deep: true });
```

and set this to display error messages,

```
ViewModel.errors.showAllMessages(true);
```

Hope it works!